# Wp_Mail and Contact Form 7

Tags: wp-mail

I have a problem. 
I've used

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from');
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name');

function new_mail_from($old) {
 return 'contact@mysite.hk';
}

function new_mail_from_name($old) { 
 return 'MySite.com';
}
```

To overwrite default From email WordPress (wordpress@mysite.com)

And this is Ok, But

Contact Form 7 Form was overwritten by the same function too. I want CF7 to send `[your-name] [your-surname] <[your-email]>` to email. Not MySite.com (contact@mysite.hk)

Is there a way to get rid of this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one

```
add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'doEmailFilter');
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'doEmailNameFilter');

function doEmailFilter($email_address){
    if($email_address === "wordpress@mysite.hk")
        return 'contact@mysite.hk';
    else
        return $email_address;
}
function doEmailNameFilter($email_from){
    if($email_from === "WordPress")
        return 'MySite.com';
    else
        return $email_from;
}
```

This checks if WP is going to send mail as a system (as wordpress@something) and if so, changes to your setting. Otherwise, is using inputs data (mail and name).